# Android, custom views don't fill the screen in a Gallery

Tags: android, gallery, android-viewpager

I want to display a custom view, composed of a TextView above an ImageView in a vertical LinearLayout, one at a time in a Gallery.

**The problem is that my custom view does not fill the screen. I can see a part of the other views on the sides and I don't want this issue.**

Here is the xml of my custom view : **gallery_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gallery_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_item_cardname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/contrebandiers_lvl1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
    />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_item_cardimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/contrebandiers_lvl1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code of the method getVew of my adapter : **GTRoundDeckAdapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    GalleryItem galleryItem;

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        galleryItem = new GalleryItem();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_item, null);
        galleryItem.cardName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_item_cardname);
        galleryItem.cardImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gallery_item_cardimg);
        convertView.setTag(galleryItem);
    }
    else
    {
        galleryItem = (GalleryItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    GTCard gtCard = (GTCard) mRoundDeck.get(position);
    galleryItem.cardName.setText(gtCard.getNameId());
    galleryItem.cardImg.setImageResource(gtCard.getImgId());

    return convertView;
}
```

I thank you for your help.

Samuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use the ViewPager instead of Gallery. In my personal experience, I have found Gallery to slightly buggy. If your requirement is to show only one View at a time, then ViewPager (which lets you swipe left and right to go one by one) should suit your needs.

You will need to include the Android Support package to use ViewPager.

Link to support package: http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html
Link on how to use ViewPager: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

Comment: Thank you for your help. ViewPager is exactly what i want ! The tutorial works fine and is simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

you should use both the width of textview and imageview fillparent.then it will be fill the screen of the gallery...